# Change Color of specific date in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm new to full calendar. But I want to integrate full calendar in my website. Everything works fine. But I've a single. [image]

As shown in the figure, I want to change the color of days from the black to red for all the events

Another Question

Tooltip is not working.

[Code.IO](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo)

I tried to follow above link for tooltip. It is working fine, when I didn't use bootstrap. But my template was totally dependent on bootstrap. Hence tooltip is not working in my templates.

Comment: if you're using bootstrap it already includes tooltip functionality. Thus you don't need tooltip.js.  See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ . So you could attach a bootstrap tooltip to the event, instead of a tooltip.js one.

Comment: "I want to change the color of days from the black to red"...it's not clear what you mean. What part is black, do you think? In your screenshot I can see red events on a white background. Please make clear precisely what you want to change. Also, please tell us which version of fullCalendar you're using, as there are some differences between the versions.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your help, i mean event date color, like 21, 22, ..., 29, I want to change these color from black to red,

Comment: @ADyson i tried to use bootstrap tooltip but it only works for title not for descriptions, ```eventRender: function (info) {
                    $(info.el).tooltip({
                        title: info.event.title
                    });
                },``` It only works for title not for description like when i replaced ```info.event,title``` into ```info.event.description``` it doesn't work

Comment: That's nothing to do with bootstrap. It's because `description` (and any other non-standard property) is accessed via `info.event.extendedProps.description` (as per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object))

Comment: To change the day number colours, just set `.fc-day-number {
  color: red;
}` in the CSS. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWaovVY . (I used the browser's element inspector to find out what element / class the numbers were wrapped in, so I could target it with a CSS rule, it wasn't too difficult.)

Comment: Thanks for you help ,  but ```.fc-day-number``` applies for all but i want for specific. like for all the event date,  eg: 20, 21, 22 ..., 29.

Comment: ok I see. well again if you look at the HTML, you'll see that each day-number is within a div which has a `data-date` attribute which shows the day it belongs to. So if you use your event data to get a list of all the dates which your event covers, you can then target each of those divs and change the colour of the fc-day-number span within it.

Comment: So it's a bit of work to code it. Do-able but a minor pain in the a**. Since it's already clear which days have events on them (because you can see the events on them!), you might want to consider whether this day-number colour change code is actually adding any value for your users or not (and therefore whether it's worth bothering to code it or not).